# Proof for uniqueness of the reduced echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this proof in my textbook that I (currently) have a small problem understanding. I took a photo of it and uploaded it here:
[image]
What I don't understand is the sentence "Either case can be expressed by writing $U \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ for some $\mathbf{x}$ whose jth entry is 1."

Does someone want to help a bit? I'm sure it's not a advanced step, but it would be nice to understand this because it occurs so early in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c_i$ is the $i$th column of $U$, and $c_j=\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\alpha_i c_i$ (where we allow the coefficients to vanish), then let $x_i=-\alpha_i$ for $i<j$, $x_j=1$ and $x_i=0$ for $i>j$. Then we indeed have $Ux=0$. Since $V$ is row equivalent to $U$, there exists some invertible matrix $E$ such that $V=EU$, hence $Vx = EUx = E0 = 0$. Finally, this implies that the $j$th column of $V$ is a linear combination of its previous columns with the same coefficients.

Comment: Jonathan Y.: Thanks! Now I understand it, it just says that we can find a x so that Ux=0... furthermore you use the property of row operations that you can multiply by an other matrix to obtain the row equivalent one, to show that also Vx=0. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, such an $x$ with $x_j=1$ and $x_i=0$ for $i>j$. And you're very welcome.